# $z=re^{i \phi} \mapsto \ln (r)+i\phi$ measurable on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory

$\log: \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\} \to C$ defined as

$$z=re^{i \phi} \mapsto \ln (r)+i\phi$$ with $\phi \in [0, 2\pi)$.

I want to show that $\log$ is measurable, that is that for every borel-set $B$ in $\mathbb{C} \simeq \mathbb{R^2}$, $\log^{-1}(B)$ is a borel-set as well.

The hint we received is that we should use that $\exp$ is injective and continuous on $[-n,n]\times[0,2\pi-\frac{1}{n}]$ but I don't know how that should help.

I know that $\log$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C} \setminus[0,\infty)$ and therefore measurable but I need to show it for $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$

Comment: Your logarithm it not continuous on $\mathbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$, it is rather continuous on $\mathbb C\setminus[0,\infty)$. For the first variant, you need to choose $\phi\in (-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it. But why is this branch of the logarith also continuous on $(0, \infty)$ as @zhw mentioned?

Comment: Hah, you probably heard of good ol' $\log\colon (0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$, the inverse of $\exp\colon \mathbb R\to (0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ is the disjoint union of the Borel sets $\mathbb C\setminus [0,\infty)$ and $(0,\infty)$. Your branch of the logarithm is continuous, hence measurable, when restricted to each of these sets. It follows that this branch of the logarithm is measurable on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}.$

Comment: So even though $\log$ isn't continuous on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ we can conclude from the continuity on $\mathbb{C} \setminus[0, \infty)$ and $(0, \infty)$ that this branch of the logarithm is measurable on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$?